# html5 "loading but not playing" event

Tags: html, events, video

I'd like to know if there is an event in html 5 for when a media is loading but can't play because it's not loaded enough, in order to make a loading icon appear. I searched everywhere but can't seem to find an answer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listent to the event `loadstart` in order to show the *loading* icon, and the event `play` (or `canplay` or `canplaythrough`, depending of what you want/need) for hiding the *loadding* icon.

Those events (and many more) are available for HTML5 media elements, like `audio` and `video`. You can check the documentation for the media events for video here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video#Media_Events